# How to parse an image url in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new here, so apologies if I am asking trivial question, but could not find answer anywhere. I need to parse my  link to display image. Image is in format e.g. p8983.png

So I build this link which is correct, not sure how to render/parse it with  ---> see line 8

`` const targetImage = `public/assets/p${playerData.player.id}.png`; ``

This don't work - see line 19
`<div><img src="{targetImage}"></img></div>`

Second issue I have is I do not know how to do math calculations on values pulled from JSON - see lines 17, 18 (all is displayed as a string) e.g.

`<div>Passes per minute: {playerData.stats[4].value} + {playerData.stats[8].value} / {playerData.stats[7].value}</div>`

Rendering and image and values after math calculations

[image: my code sample]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<img src={targetImage}>`? Otherwise you're creating a string that literally is `"{targetImage}"` (no variable interpolation).

Comment: Thank you @Dave Moten, it worked, you are right it was so obvious.

Comment: @Dave Moten, pleast post this as an answer and I can mark you as correct, so you can ean your well deserved points

Comment: Ah, you should thank @Aurora0001. I just fixed a bit of spelling!

Comment: @maciejk77 posted as an answer (assuming you did want me to do that!). Glad it helped you!

Comment: @maciejk77 is my answer clear enough for you to mark it as accepted, or do you need any more clarification?

Answer (score 2):

There's a subtle difference between your code and what you want: `<img src="{targetImage}">` sets your image's source to literally be the string `"{targetImage}"`, which is obviously invalid. The correct format for React props is `<img src={targetImage}>`, which should produce the desired output.

Make sure you read [JSX in Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) from Facebook to learn the differences so you can avoid mistakes like this and get a better understanding of JSX and React; it should help you understand what you did wrong!